# Prepend text to beginning of file names

Tags: shell, for-loop, prepend

I would like to prepend a string of text to the beginning of each file in a directory. The string is `uniwisc`.

When I run the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

url="ftp://rammftp.cira.colostate.edu/Lindsey/spc/ir/"

wget -r -nd --no-parent -nc -P /awips2/edex/data/goes14/ $url

find /awips2/edex/data/goes14/ -type f -exec cp {} /awips2/edex/data/uniwisc/ \;

for f in /awips2/edex/data/uniwisc/*; 
    do
    f="$(basename $f)"
    mv "$f" "uniwisc.$f"
    done;

find /awips2/edex/data/uniwisc/ -type f -mmin -6 -exec mv {} /awips2/edex/data/manual/ \;
exit 0
```

I get the error `mv: cannot stat '<filenames>' "No such file or directory.`

Comment: When accessing variables, it is usually good practice to enclose them in quotes unless you're positive that there are no whitespace characters or you want that behaviour. In this situation, you should have `"$f"` instead of `$f`. An example of where code similar to what you wrote would fail is if you tried to move the file 'happy me'. You would get an error message stating that the file 'happy' doesn't exist followed by an error message stating that the file 'me' doesn't exist (assuming the individual files 'happy' and 'me' don't exist),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways that you can do that.

Using paramater expansion, which is built into the bash shell:

```
for f in <dir path>/*; do
    mv "$f" "${f%/*}/uniwisc.${f##*/}"
done
```

Using the rename command:

```
rename 's!^!uniwisc.!' *
```

Using the `basename`, as CodeGnome suggested:

```
for f in <dir path>/*; do
    mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/uniwisc.$(basename "$f")"
done
```

I was going to write more methods, but there are a lot of them and they don't change significantly. Personally, I'd use the rename command in that situation.

Comment: Be careful with the loops above, they do not preserve directory information, and be careful with the `rename` command, it has no builtin safeguards, if you have permissions to write, it will write regardless. Double check before renaming critical files.

Comment: Thank you, David. I am using the echo command to see what happens prior to actually invoking the real command. I also tried the "move" command, but ran into the following issue, "No such file or directory." When executing using echo, it does rename it correctly, but when invoking the command without echo gives that error. Should I be adding a path in there?

Comment: I think I was missing a quotation mark, which gave me the error. +1

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I agree that you have to be really careful with the `rename` command. I think it should be used sparingly and only if you're really comfortable with regular expressions. In fact, I created a temporary directory, with files, to run my commands against. I forgot to change the directory and prepended 'uniwisc.' to all the file names. Had the command removed information from the file name, I would have needed to check a backup for the original names.

Comment: @JustinBalbierer I prepended the path of the file in the examples I gave because without it your files would be moved to the current working directory. I believe that was what David C. Rankin was referring to.

Comment: Thank you, Dave F. The goal is to keep the prepended files in the same directory and then move them using the "find" command to identify files younger than 6 minutes. The code `for f in <dir path>/*; do
    mv "$f" "${f%/*}/uniwisc.${f##*/}"
done` actually worked the best so far.